# Why do I get an empty plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, topic-modeling

I'm doing a topic model and I'm using matplotlib to visualize the results. I would like to plot word counts and the weights of keywords in one chart. The dataframe has the data, but the plot is empty. Could anybody help me, what is wrong with the code?

```
from collections import Counter
topics = final_model.show_topics(formatted=False)
data_flat = [w for w_list in Tweet_df.tokens for w in w_list]
counter = Counter(data_flat)

out = []
for i, topic in topics:
   for word, weight in topic:
       out.append([word, i , weight, counter[word]])

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['word', 'topic_id', 'importance', 'word_count'])     

print(df)   

# Plot Word Count and Weights of Topic Keywords
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(16,10), sharey=True, dpi=160)
cols = [color for name, color in mcolors.TABLEAU_COLORS.items()]
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
   ax.bar(x='word', height="word_count", data=df.loc[df.topic_id==i, :], color=cols[i], width=0.5, alpha=0.3, label='Word Count')
   ax_twin = ax.twinx()
   ax_twin.bar(x='word', height="importance", data=df.loc[df.topic_id==i, :], color=cols[i], width=0.2, label='Weights')
   ax.set_ylabel('Word Count', color=cols[i])
   ax_twin.set_ylim(0, 0.030); ax.set_ylim(0, 3500)
   ax.set_title('Topic: ' + str(i), color=cols[i], fontsize=16)
   ax.tick_params(axis='y', left=False)
   ax.set_xticklabels(df.loc[df.topic_id==i, 'word'], rotation=30, horizontalalignment= 'right')
   ax.legend(loc='upper left'); ax_twin.legend(loc='upper right')

fig.tight_layout(w_pad=2)
fig.suptitle('Word Count and Importance of Topic Keywords', fontsize=22, y=1.05)    
plt.show()
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Does replacing `plt.show()` with `fig.show()` help? Mixing matplotlib's state machine and OOP APIs is usually asking for trouble.

Comment: Please, include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help your without the ability to test what you did.

Comment: Do you get some error message? Is your plot completely white without axes? How does the output of `print(df)` look like?